# Strange behavior gridview - onItemClick

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I have a problem with gridview. I have 7 columns gridview but when I click on any column on one row i get index of first item in a row.

For example when i click on third column on second row a get index 7, but should be 10.

I extend BaseAdapter for this.

```
    CalendarAdapter adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), dateFormat.format(month.getTime()), issues, height, getDays(month));
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(calendarItemClickListener);
```

...

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener calendarItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + i); // here is bad index
    }
};
```

Adapter:

```
public CalendarAdapter(Activity c, String monthCalendar, List<Issue> items, float height, List<Calendar> dates) {
    this.dates = dates;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dates.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Position: " + position + ", " + dateFormat.format(dates.get(position).getTime()));
    return hashMap.get(dateFormat.format(dates.get(position).getTime()));
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return dateFormat.format(dates.get(position).getTime()).contains(month);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_calendar, null);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams param = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                (int) (height / ROW_NUMBER),
                (int) (height / ROW_NUMBER));
        convertView.setLayoutParams(param);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dayView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.downloadViewButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadViewButton);
        holder.previewImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.preview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

...

XML

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Know anybody why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code where You click, initialize GridView and if You have a custom adapter, also this

Comment: post your getview method also.

Comment: getView is posted now, only begining, other have no efect.